# jQuery: give precedence to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to give precedence to an event? So in the below example it always fires the div1 event first but I want to fire the div2 event first. I could move div2 outside of the div1 div but it would include a bit more work because of other things (which I will do if it's the best option).

Also, is this a modern method? I know people talk about using .on over .live, but I don't think .click has a problem does it?

```
<div id="div1">
    Various content etc.
    <div id="div2">XXclickable content hereXX</div>
</div>

$('#div1').click(function(e) {
    alert("clicked 1");
});
$('#div2').click(function(e) {
    alert("clicked 2");
});
```

Comment: This should help: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I think [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) is what you need... Or test for the current target under your cursor.

Comment: Thanks but I can't see how that helps. I want to fire div2 first, but it fires div1 first. If I stop it at div2 it would never fire div1. Maybe an 'ignore-event' but not a stop-all-events. Thanks though.

Comment: yeah thats correct add `e.stopPropagation()` before your alert and you will be good

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on JSFiddle, with every version on jQuery available, on both Firefox and Chrome and the `div2` event in your example code always fired first. And from my understanding of even propagation/bubbling, this would have always been the case.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gozek9hs/)

Event delegation would probably be a better idea regardless. That is to say, not attaching an event handler directly to `div2` in the first place, but adding additional logic to the `div1` handler and checking the `event.target` for identity of the caller.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gozek9hs/1/)